# Videos Full Screen to the Wrong Monitor

Tags: firefox, flash

I am using firefox. If I open one video using flash player in full screen in the second screen it opens in the first screen, This problem is only in the firefox. In chrome, I do not have this problem. Can anyone help Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that this is a bug in Flash Player; Adobe stopped releasing new versions of Flash Player for Linux a while ago, so unfortunately it's unlikely to get fixed. However, Chrome uses a different, more up-to-date version of Flash that is not available in Firefox.